stylex.mjs:174 Uncaught Error: 'stylex.create' should never be called at runtime. It should be compiled away by '@stylexjs/babel-plugin
I'm encountering an error when using StyleX in a React application. The error message states: "stylex.mjs:174 Uncaught Error: 'stylex.create' should never be called at runtime. It should be compiled away by '@stylexjs/babel-plugin'".
I'm unsure why this error is occurring and how to resolve it.
